# How can I manage the drop down field lists in Search Builder?

Tags: search, custom-fields

I upgraded a site from 4.2 to 4.4.

They use Search Builder to run specific searches against custom data, and build quarterly reports.

Previously the field list in search builder was grouped by data set so related fields were listed next to each other. There now seems to be no underlying order to the listing and site users are finding it difficult to build their searches.

Does anyone know what governs the field listing? is there somewhere I can go to re-order the list in a way that makes sense to the end user?

Answer (score 1):

These lists are generated programmatically now, and are basically alphabetical.  While I would encourage your users to give it a little more time to adapt, you could reorder the steps  with a jQuery script.  Consider [adding a .extra.tpl file](https://civicrm.org/blogs/dave-greenberg/now-its-easier-add-custom-behaviors-templates) with your script in your custom templates folder in `CRM/Contact/Form/Search/Builder.extra.tpl`.

Comment: Thanks Jon,

If it requires a script I'll need to pass it on to a colleague.

Although the list as I view it is definitely not Alphabetical, so I wondered if there is anything else that can be affecting it.

Cheers

Craig